# How to get skew from intrinics/distortion

Tags: opencv

I have the camera intrinsics matrix and the distortion coefficients from OpenCV camera calibration.

Am an wondering where the skew factor of the calibration is contained in this Matrices and how I can get it as a float or float[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skew is by default set to 0 at least since OpenCV 2.0.

If you look at the camera matrix it looks like A = [fx skew u0; 0 fy v0; 0 0 1]

but in OpenCv it is A = [fx 0 u0; 0 fy v0; 0 0 1].

Comment: Do you know, if it is possible to do a calibration with openCV where the skew isn't 0. The images I have to process are taken with a linescan, so the skew isn't guaranteed to be 0.